# Using ROP to access a shell in ARM

Tags: security, arm, libc, exploit

As an assignment in a computer design course my team has to access shell using return oriented programming by overflowing a buffer and making use of several gadgets we have found.

Using GDB we found the location of the string "/bin/sh" with the following command:

```
(GDB) find &system, +9999999, "/bin/sh"
```

Then using several gadgets we are able to load it into r0 and from there we are able to jump into .

Unfortunately each time we run into a segment fault right before we get access to the terminal. We are pretty lost on this one, and could use whatever help you could give us. Do any of you know of any common errors that cause this?

Our stack looks like this right before we go through our gadgets and enter system:

```
(gdb) x/15a $sp
0xbefffb40: 0x85a4  0x42424141  0x44444343  0x46464545
0xbefffb50: 0xbeff0046  0xb6f55108 <inet6_opt_finish+56>    0xb6f84a60  
            0xb6f55104 <inet6_opt_finish+52>
0xbefffb60: 0x0 0xb6ea3f6c <__libc_system>  0x0 0x84d0 <main>
0xbefffb70: 0xb6ffc718  0xb6ffc400  0x0
```

and after getting into system:

```
(gdb) x/10a $sp
0xbefffb68: 0x0 0x84d0 <main>   0xb6ffc718  0xb6ffc400
0xbefffb78: 0x0 0x0 0x83bc <_start> 0x0
0xbefffb88: 0x0 0x0
```

Comment: What are you trying to run?  The text `"/bin/sh"`?  You need to run `execv()` syscall or something like that.  You need to add more information to your question.  Did you use the ROP gadget finder on the binary?  Can you show which ones you choose?

Comment: We are trying to run <__libc_system> with argument "bin/sh/" stored in r0 in order to get shell. We found the gadgets manually using grep. We will edit the post to contain the dissasembled gadgets.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's your main program is looking like but looks like i had this before. The crash is probably because you are jumping/returning into a thumb subroutine, the `__libc_system()` function for Android 5.0,1 at least, is in thumb. From the document [ARM Procedure call standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) (Page 17 section 5.3) if your target is in thumb, the target address of your return must +1 so `0xb6ea3f6c <__libc_system>` should be `0xb6ea3f6d`